# Android start activity by Item

Tags: android, arrays, list, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I have an array that I display in a AlertDialog, I want to start an activity at the click of the line and pass some data.
I created this code, but if it is the array has three elements, are opened three activities. where am I wrong? thanks

```
 final String[] choiceList = nome_op;
 final String[] idOperatoriList = id_nome_op;
  builder2.setItems(choiceList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            for (int i = 0; i < choiceList.length; i++) {
                Intent singole_usc = new Intent(getActivity(), Inserisci_m.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("id", idOperatoriList[item]);
                extras.putLong("data", calendarioFooter.getTimeInMillis());
                singole_usc.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(singole_usc);
            }
        }
    })
...
```

Comment: You placed the startActivity method in a condition-less loop. It'll obviously open the same number of activities as the length of choiceList array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to take your code out of the for loop. Like so,

```
 final String[] choiceList = nome_op;
 final String[] idOperatoriList = id_nome_op;
  builder2.setItems(choiceList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            Intent singole_usc = new Intent(getActivity(), Inserisci_m.class);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("id", idOperatoriList[item]);
            extras.putLong("data", calendarioFooter.getTimeInMillis());
            singole_usc.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(singole_usc);

    }
})
```

The index variable i is never used in the block anyways.

Answer (score 0):

have the startActivity() outside the for loop

```
Intent singole_usc = new Intent(getActivity(),
for (int i = 0;
i < choiceList.length; i++) {
    Inserisci_m.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("id", idOperatoriList[item]);
    extras.putLong("data", calendarioFooter.getTimeInMillis());
    singole_usc.putExtras(extras);
}

startActivity(singole_usc);
```